# Can I get a specific folder size instead of overall Google Drive size through Google Drive API?

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to get the specific folder size with the Google cloud REST API.

I have tried for "**about**" method with REST API but in this method I am getting the Total used bytes and total available free space for my overall cloud storage.

But I want a total size of specific folder in google cloud with API.

So, Is there any way to get the specific folder size in google cloud drive API.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Whilst I agree with @pinoyyid's answer, I do disagree with their reasoning.

Just because the file structure is effectively flat doesn't mean that you can't derive a folder size.

A lovely example of something that does this is this app -https://gdrivefoldersize.appspot.com/

**N.B:** Due to the way Google Drive is designed, a file/folder can be in multiple locations, which feels more like `symlink`. As such, you may get an inaccurate size for a folder and therefore an unrepresentative total size of the drive if the file/folder sizes were all added up separately.

Comment: Thanks for this! I am the developer of that app :) While simple, it is being used but several people so far. In the recycle bin on Google Drive you can't sort by Size confirming this is indeed on purpose by Google.

Comment: @sfratini I would very appreciate it if you would be so kind upload your code to GitHub or similar so that other developers might be able to understand how it works and how to implement the same functionality in their own code bases. As it currently stands, whilst I like your app, I can't allow it to run in my organization as I can't see what else it's doing.

Comment: @sfratini would be great to see your approach. Are you looping through all files and adding the size (bottom - up) ?

Comment: @user26631 This is what I am actually doing: I paginate over the folder and to a recursive function checking if it is a file or folder. For every item, I store the ID and space used in LocalStorage so I don't have to do a lot of service calls. Like a cache. Then if it is a file, I query the Google API and store the "Quota Used" property. If it is a folder, I call the function again. It usually takes some time to analyse because I can only query up to 10 items at a time in the API. I am using Quota Used because that is actually the space is using in your quota and not all files do so.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way you would consider creating a gist or project for this? I'm just getting into Google App Scripting but would also enjoy the challenge of writing it for myself.

Comment: A small tooltip explaining double counting would be enough to manage users' expectations

Answer (score 0):

You can get the specific folder size (the amount of files and total size) with a simple Google App:

https://github.com/zpf7879/GoogleAppScript/blob/main/README.md

Answer (score -1):

No there isn't, nor will there be. You need to understand that in Drive, files do NOT live within a folder. Rather, having a parent folder is simply an attribute of a file.

Comment: If they can list all files within the folder they should be able to sum up their sizes